# When is it appropriate to use 'auto' in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, auto

I'm struggling to come up with some consistent rules for myself for when to use 'auto' in a C++ program.  Here are my pro/con lists, perhaps you can help me by giving me your input.

Pro:

- 'auto' is good for avoiding complex and large template declarations (e.g. the classic use case of auto to define the iteration variable over an STL container)
- 'auto' is good for future-proofing code.  For example, if I have an array of ints and I want to change it to unsigned ints, if I've used 'auto' when I refer to elements of that array, things will automatically update.  Of course, that would also have occurred had I used a typedef for the array.

Cons:

- 'auto' makes it hard to read code.  I have no idea if the declaration is a pointer or value.  I have no idea if it might have a constructor and destructor.
- 'auto' makes me lazy.  I can forget about the types and just write code.  But in C++, the types are very important to the semantics of the program.

**When does you guys use Auto? and when do you prefer not to use it?**

Comment: The types are very important *to the compiler*.  :P  The *names* are what's important for semantics.  JMNSHO.

Comment: I always use auto except for `size_t` (in loops, i.e. `size_t i = 0,...`  this avoids `i` beeing an `int`). The variables should tell what it is and how to use it. it's all about names.

Comment: I use auto only when I'm forced to. I think the type is as important as the variable name, the code is a lot more self-describing without auto.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180216/does-auto-make-c-code-harder-to-understand

Comment: My answer justifies use of `auto` for Expression Templates where it is **almost impossible** to write the type manually for complex expressions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900459/the-new-keyword-auto-when-should-it-be-used-to-declare-a-variable-type

Comment: I believe this[http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180216/does-auto-make-c-code-harder-to-understand/180616#180616] qualifies as a reference to specific expertise (backed up by facts).

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow. Programmers is better, but it looks like it (or at least a very similar variant) has already been asked.