# Find usages of type, referenced as auto, in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, auto

In the discussions about using auto or not in c++, one side says that it is hard to see where you use a certain type, when you do not explicitly write it, but use auto. The other side says that with a modern ide, you can easily find this information.

Using visual studio 2017 I note that finding references do not point to auto usages. In the following, find references will point to these lines only

> struct MyType
>
> MyType foo()
>
> void bar(MyType mt)

and not to the two lines in main, where the type, though not explicit, is in fact in use.

> auto q = foo();
>
> bar(q);

```
struct MyType{};

MyType foo()
{
    return MyType();
}

void bar(MyType mt){ }

int main(int value)
{
    auto q = foo();
    bar(q);
}
```

The question then being... is that not a problem in relation to this discussion? Alternatively, is there a way to make visual studio give all usages of MyType, when when it is auto realized.

Comment: The answer to your question is really subjective. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900459/the-new-keyword-auto-when-should-it-be-used-to-declare-a-variable-type.

Comment: It's not just `auto`. There's also `template <typename T>` which might be instantiated with `T==MyType`.