# Traversing a string in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am looking for something similar to traversing a string in Python:

i.e.

```
for char in str:
    do something
```

How can I do this in C++?

Thank you

Comment: it depends on what str is..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

if `str` is `std::string`, or some other standard container of `char`, then that's

```
for (char c : str) {
    // do something
}
```

If you want to modify the characters of the string, then you'll want a reference `char & c` rather than a value `char c`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is what he's looking for, but... In Python, his `char` would have type string, and in his `do something`, he could do string like operations on it.  (On the other hand, he couldn't modify the character in `str`, because `char` would be a one character long substring of `std`.)

Comment: OP should specify what he wants otherwise the answers aren't precise enough

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed, I'm not trying to exactly emulate Python semantics, since that would probably be a bad idea even if I knew Python. This is just "something similar to traversing a string in Python".

Comment: in c++17, this [will probably become](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm) `for (c : str) { ... }`

Answer (score 13):

With a [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) it's going to be quite easy:

```
std::string myStr = "Hello";
for (char c : myStr)
    std::cout << c; // Print out every character
```

or by reference in case you want to modify it..

```
std::string myStr = "Hello";
for (char& c : myStr)
    c = 'A';
// mystr = "AAAAA"
```

Comment: @NeilKirk I don't think you can edit the string much using a python loop either. Since your using C++11, you can use `auto` and `auto&`...

Comment: @matsjoyce But why?  That would just be obfuscation.

Comment: @JamesKanze But auto is the best thing ever! Which is easier to read: `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<A*>>::const_iterator& iter;` or `auto iter;`? Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434971/how-much-is-too-much-with-c0x-auto-keyword).

Comment: @matsjoyce: But this is a `char`, not a crazy nested (or unnamable) type. All `auto` does here is make it slightly harder to figure the type out.

Comment: @matsjoyce: Not really. It'll update the type for you, but not the semantics of whatever you're doing with it. For example, the first loop here will break due to the use of `cout` rather than `wcout`. But this is getting rather off-topic. Lets just agree that, here, you *can* use `auto` but it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @matsjoyce On the contrary.  It will mean that when you go looking for all of the `char`, to find where you need to fix the logic, you won't find this one.

Comment: Marco, both yours and Mike's are great somewhat identical answers. Occam's razor made the selection for best answer. :)

Comment: Glad that you liked my answer. No worries, Mike's often more concise than me. I upvoted his answer too

Answer (score 0):

use range based for loop like this

```
char a1[5] = {'a', 'a', 'a', 'c'};
for (auto a : a1)
    cout << a << endl;
```

Comment: A non-null-terminated char array is not what people usually refer to by "string"

Comment: And some indentation/consistent formatting probably wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You probably don't want to use this construct over a C-style character array (even if you do have a reason for using such an evil entity), since you'll iterate over the terminator as well as the string characters.

Comment: It doesn't even work with a `char*` C style string. And for a `char[N]` it will iterate past any `\0`.