# When to use the auto keyword?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have been reading about the auto specifier, when should you use it. I see the benefits of it, but in production code is it usually used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434971/how-much-is-too-much-with-c0x-auto-keyword

Comment: I don't know how my fingers survived for 20 years without it. Is it used in production code? *Every day* if I'm the one writing it.

Comment: Yes, it is used very commonly by c++ coders.

Comment: Almost Always. Forget that: always.