# auto variable as a function parameter with > C++11 only

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

IIUC, I can't use `auto` variable as a function parameter with C++11, but it might be possible with C++14.

Is this true?

I believe whoever closed it is wrong - gcc-4.9 is not even C++11 compliant and definitely not C++14. So how the answer is helpful in this case?

Comment: @Barry, Sorry you are wrong. gcc-4.9 is not even C++11 compliant and so you can't possibly solve it with the post you referenced.

Comment: You should read the answers of the linked question. They answer your question (and the answer is no).

Answer (score 1):

In a lambda, yes.

A lambda expression can use auto as a function parameter type in C++14.

From the Microsoft Developer Network [Lambada Expressions C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx)

**In C++ 14, if the parameter type is generic, you can use the auto keyword as the type specifier. This tells the compiler to create the function call operator as a template. Each instance of auto in a parameter list is equivalent to a distinct type parameter.**

```
auto y = [] (auto first, auto second)
{
    return first + second;
};
```

In C++ 14, ISO C++ still forbids it as a general function parameter. The compiler will give you errors.

In short, you cannot use it in general functions. You may only use it in a lambda function.

Comment: ok, so I still can't write something like int MyClass::Foo(auto param); right? it is available only in lambda?

Comment: If you know how to use lambadas and pointers, you can work around it.

Comment: Side note, from how you worded this, it sounded like you use auto everywhere you can. I would read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434971/how-much-is-too-much-with-c11-auto-keyword) to get a general idea of how messy auto can be. It's fairly new, so it has it's own issues.

Comment: It's lambda, not lambada. [Lambada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambada) is something quite different.

Comment: Sorry, auto correct got me. Wrote this on my phone.

Comment: @DarmaniLink, no I am not using it everywhere. I was hoping to solve "virtual template" problem with auto.

Comment: Just kind of from the wording you were using, it was implied.

Comment: I don't get the "setting Y to the **return value of the lambda** part. The code sets `y` to the lambda, not its return value. `auto z = y(3,4)` would set `z` to the **return value of the lambda**.