# C++ auto keyword: how to avoid breaking IDE features in qtcreator

Tags: qt-creator

It seems the world is generally very pro-auto:
[How much is too much with C++11 auto keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434971/how-much-is-too-much-with-c11-auto-keyword)

Having to work myself into the code base of a large project, I find it quite frustrating that the usage of auto breaks handy IDE features, mostly jumping to the declaration of a variable or function. Also refactoring seems to break here.
Is there a plug-in or anything that helps qtcreator deducing the types?

I am using QtCreator 4.2.0 and I am currently stuck with this, so, would need a solution that works there

Comment: Update your IDE / use another one

Comment: thanks... unfortunately, I am stuck with qtcreator

Comment: although, I wouldnt mind a different IDE for just reading through the code initially. any suggestions for something lightweight that is fixes my problem?

Comment: I haven't been developing much with c++ lately but for this same reason I installed CLion from JetBrains that seems to handle auto keyword way better then QtCreator. Note that it's not free but it does come with a free trail.

Comment: @chrise give a try to codeblocks or vscode

Comment: Why are you stuck with Qt Creator 4.2.0? Try to use 4.5.1 instead, that should solve all/most of your problems.

Comment: I faced the same issue and then updated Qt creator to its latest 8.0.0. There this issue got fixed.