# Is there an auto keyword in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

I'm learning Delphi myself.. I have seen the `auto` variable type that can do some degree of magic in C++. Is there an `auto` a variable type, or something similar to this, in Delphi?

Comment: In Delphi 10.3 and later, you can simply write `var a := RHS`; the type of `a` will be the type of the right-hand side.

Comment: With that said, the use cases for `var` in Delphi are not as extensive [as those for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6434971/327083) - prefer using explicit types unless you have a **very** compelling reason not to.

Comment: https://www.embarcadero.com/resources/white-papers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`auto` in C++ is used to let the compiler infer a variable's data type based on what type of value is used to initialize it.

In Delphi 10.3 and later, [type inference](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Inline_Variable_Declaration#Type_Inference_for_Inlined_Variables) is available only on an [inline variable](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Inline_Variable_Declaration):

> Additionally, the compiler can now in several circumstances **infer the type of a variable at its inline declaration location**, by looking to the type of the value assigned to it.
>
> ```
> procedure Test;
> begin
>   var I := 22;
>   ShowMessage (I.ToString);
> end;
> ```
>
> The type of the r-value expression (that is, what comes after the `:=`) is analyzed to determine the type of the variable. Some of the data types are “expanded” to a larger type, as in the case above where the numeric value 22 (a `ShortInt`) is expanded to `Integer`. As a general rule, if the right hand expression type is an integral type and smaller than 32 bits, the variable will be declared as a 32-bit `Integer`. You can use an explicit type if you want a specific, smaller, numeric type.